# Unit testing fs-extra writeFile

Tags: node.js, angular, jestjs

I have used `writeFile` from `fs-extra` to generate my file When I tried to do unit testing using JEST I'm always getting an error like the `writeFile` method was not called even though it has been called. Can someone plz suggest me ways to get it tested properly.

These are the functions I'm using.
Note: No class has been used, we are consuming it as methods

```
import { writeFile } from 'fs-extra';
import { resolve as pathResolve } from 'path';

export default async function generateFile(): Promise<void>{
   await writeSampleFile(value);
   // other stuffs
}

async function writeSampleFile(value: string): Promise<void> {
  try {
    await writeFile(pathResolve(path), value, 'utf8');
  } catch (err) {
  }
}
```

`spec.ts`:

```
import generateFile from './x';
import * as fsExtra from 'fs-extra';

const writeFileSpy = jest.spyOn(fsExtra, 'writeFile');


describe('writeFile', async () => {
  test('it should check whether writeFile has been called', async () => {
    await generateFile();
    //Since internally it was calling writeFile i was checking for writeSampleFile as well
    expect(writeFileSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Though I have called everything I'm not getting the method as called and the test got failed but my file is getting generated using the `writeFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `async/await` syntax with `describe`. Otherwise, it will throw error:

> Returning a Promise from "describe" is not supported. Tests must be defined synchronously.
>
> Returning a value from "describe" will fail the test in a future version of Jest.

And, if you use `import * as fsExtra from 'fs-extra'`

make sure that the values of `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` configurations are `false` in your `tsconfig.json`

If you use `import fsExtra from 'fs-extra'`, you should make sure these two configurations' values are `true` in your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { writeFile } from 'fs-extra';
import { resolve as pathResolve } from 'path';

export default async function generateFile(value): Promise<void> {
  await writeSampleFile(value);
}

async function writeSampleFile(value: string): Promise<void> {
  try {
    await writeFile(pathResolve('some path'), value, 'utf8');
  } catch (err) {}
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import generateFile from './';
import fsExtra from 'fs-extra';

const writeFileSpy = jest.spyOn(fsExtra, 'writeFile');

describe('writeFile', () => {
  test('it should check whether writeFile has been called', async () => {
    await generateFile('jest');
    expect(writeFileSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58625148/index.spec.ts
  writeFile
    ✓ it should check whether writeFile has been called (28ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.513s, estimated 9s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58625148

Comment: Im getting error like  Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given on this line  const writeFileSpy = jest.spyOn(fsExtra, 'writeFile');

Comment: @AD_SK The error means `fsExtra.writeFile` is `undefined`, jest can't spy on an `undefined` value. Update the answer, please check. My code sample works fine.

Comment: If I modify the values also I'm getting the same error

Comment: @AD_SK Can you put your minimal reproduced code on https://codesandbox.io and share it. I will help you check.